# Is there a reason why MtGox is based in Japan?

Tags: exchanges, mtgox

I was wondering why MtGox is a Japanese company. The founder was American, and the current owner is French, so is there a special reason why Japan was attractive for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mtgox owner was already in japan and already had his company there when he decided to buy mtgox from historical owner Jed in 2011.

- mtgox owner s blog : http://blog.magicaltux.net/
- hosting company that existed years before he decided to buy mtgox : http://legal.tibanne.com/ , services on https://www.kalyhost.com/